# App rejection - how to prove that there's no private API usage

Tags: ios, api

I recently had an app rejected because it called a private API - 'hideKeyboard'. It's a little unfortunate since the code snippet in question was something that I'd pulled off the web and then decided not to use. Although the code was never called, I'd forgotten to remove it (and I had no idea that it called a private API).

So, I removed the code and resubmitted, however it was then rejected again for the same reason.

I searched all my code and any 3rd party libraries to no avail. I then used the strings utility on the original app binary and verified that hideKeyboard was indeed listed. Finally I used it on the new binary (also submitted to Apple) and there was no sign of it.

I suspect that Apple may have rescanned the first binary again - has anyone here every experienced that error?

Is there any tool that I can use to prove that I'm not calling the 'hideKeyboard' function

I've lodged an appeal, but I fear that this is becoming messy and will now take a long time to resolve.

Regards,

Tim

Comment: are u sure you pushed the right new code to apple ?

Comment: That was my first thought, however I've only submitted twice, and both archives are marked as "Sumbitted" in the Xcode organizer. Also, I'd fixed a second issue that didn't then cause a problem during review, so they must have at least tested the second binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple had indeed made an error in rescanning the old binary. The app was quickly reviewed and accepted.

Answer (score 3):

since Xcode 4.3 you can check for the use of private API. But as long as the Xcode is in beta mode you cannot submit with it. 
So just install it, try to validate your app in the organizer or directly in the Project Build settings (The "Validate Built Product" setting).
Fix everything that might be wrong and resubmit your app. It should be ok then ;)